# Merge only specific lines of a GitHub pull request?

Tags: github

I would like to merge most of the code in a pull request commit, while omitting a section of the commit. What is the best way to go about this? Do I fork their fork and manually make my changes?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can cherry-pick their commit:

```
git cherry-pick -n [commit]
```

and then unstage, then re-add the patches you want:

```
git reset
git add -p
git commit
```

`git add -p` will let you interactively select the changes you want to include.

But how you want to go about this obviously depends on the context of why you're trying to partially include some of someone's changes. If you're just grabbing a feature from someone else's fork for your own repo this is fine. If you're a coworker on a project, you should make a separate commit with the deleted code explaining why you removed it.